# FTP,Blackraccoon Memory leaks

Tags: ios, ftp, automatic-ref-counting, blackraccoon

I am working with Blackraccoon FTP client to do FTP operations,working with ARC.but i am getting leaks in instruments.

but there were no leaks in sample application here is my code

```
 BRRequestCreateDirectory  *createEventDir = [BRRequestCreateDirectory initWithDelegate:nil];
//NSString *EventCode = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:kEventCodeKey];
createEventDir.path = @"/12341234";
createEventDir.hostname = @"media.example.com/httpdocs/events/";
createEventDir.username = @"badboy";
createEventDir.password = @"hai!";
createEventDir.tag = 103;
[createEventDir start];
createEventDir = nil;
```

**sample code from FTP clent** [Blackraccoon FTP client](https://github.com/lloydsargent/BlackRaccoon)

[image]

leaks showing  in instruments like,but i am using ARC
can any one help me to solve this prob..

Comment: Solved memory leaks and crashes.. the problem is not with BlackRaccoon its working good.. for my needs i changed the BRRequestDelegate. problem solved by changing delegate property to unsafe__unretained.

Answer (score 2):

I ported and heavily modified BlackRaccoon. It is designed to use delegates. In other words, delegates are required.

```
BRRequestCreateDirectory  *createEventDir = [BRRequestCreateDirectory      initWithDelegate:nil];
//NSString *EventCode = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]     stringForKey:kEventCodeKey];
createEventDir.path = @"/12341234";
createEventDir.hostname = @"media.example.com/httpdocs/events/";
createEventDir.username = @"badboy";
createEventDir.password = @"hai!";
createEventDir.tag = 103;
[createEventDir start];
createEventDir = nil;
```

Is incorrect. It starts a lot of things going and then deletes the object - the action is undefined.

Instead you need something as indicated in the code that I provided (that doesn't leak).

First, the class that uses the ftp needs to have BRRequestDelegate to indicate the delegate protocol.

```
- (IBAction) createDirectory:(id)sender
{
    //----- createEventDir must be a variable in your class...

    createEventDir = [BRRequestCreateDirectory initWithDelegate: self];

    createEventDir.path = @"/12341234;
    createEventDir.hostname = @"media.example.com/httpdocs/events/";
    createEventDir.username = @"badboy";
    createEventDir.password = @"hai!";
    [createEventDir start];

    //----- createEventDir MUST NOT BE DELETED OR SET TO NIL HERE
}
```

Then you have to have the two delegates (at a minimum):

```
-(void) requestCompleted: (BRRequest *) request
{
    //----- handle Create Directory
    if (request == createEventDir)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@ completed!", request);
        //----- everything is done, NOW you can set it to nil
        createEventDir = nil;
    }
}  

-(void) requestFailed: (BRRequest *) request
{
    if (request == createEventDir)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", request.error.message);
        //----- everything is done, NOW you can set it to nil
        createEventDir = nil;
    }
}
```

If you go back and look at my test code you'll see how things work. If you are still having issues, post in the issues on http://github.com/lloydsargent/BlackRaccoon

Hopefully this will get you past your problem.